# Trouble understanding Question. $Sym(n \times n)$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $Sym(n \times n) =\{A \in Mat(n \times n,K)\ \mid\ A^{T}=A\}$. Show that $Sym(n \times n)$ is a subspace of the vector space $Mat(n \times n,K)$.

I think I'm misunderstanding the question. It is not entirely clear in which respect $Sym$ to what vectorspace is a subvectorspace but I think it's reasonable to assume it's meant to be $A \in Mat$ with $A^{T}=A$. But this is trivial since the two vectorspaces are obviously equal. So I think I'm not understanding the question properly. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to provide more information. 1) what is $Sym(n×n) $ ? 2) what is your base field $K$  ? 3) To talking about a linear subspace, you need to specify the mother space .

Answer (score 1):

The set of all $n\times n $ matrices over a field $k$ is a vector space as $ M+N$ is such a matrix where $M$ and $N$ are such matrices and also $kM$ defined entry-wise as $[kM]_{ij}=k[M]_{ij}$ is a marix as well. The symmetric matrices are a vector subspace of this vector space as you can show.

Comment: Ok thanky ou this helps

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$Sym(n×n)= \{ A∈Mat(n×n,K) :  A^T=A \}$. Show that $Sym(n×n) $ is a subspace of $Mat(n×n , K) $

If this is your question, then take $ A, B \in Symm(n×n) $ and $\lambda \in  K $

$( A+\lambda B)^T = A^T + \lambda B^T = A+\lambda B$ .
Hence , $A+\lambda B\in Symm(n×n) $

One interesting way  (but here not too interesting) to prove a subset $U$  is a linear subspace of some space $V$ , is to define a linear map $T$ from $V$ to some linear space $W$ such that $Null(T) = U$.

Here, $T: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ defined by

$T(A) ={A^T}- A$

Then , for $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$  and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $

$T(A+\lambda B) =T(A) + \lambda B$

$Null(T) =\{ A\in M_n(\mathbb{R}) : T(A) = 0 \} $

$= Symm_n(\mathbb{R})$